# How do I side load a serialization of the current scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, active-model-serializers

I'd like to append a serialization of the current scope with my json response. While the current scope is available to the `ActiveModel:: Serializer`, it's not necessarily associated with the model being serialized; so I'm unsure how to include it.

My first instinct is to just create a wrapper which merges the model serialization and scope serialization. I think this wrapper would break some conventions though.

Is there a pattern for side-loading this context?